# Problem with transferring int from python 3 to esp 32

Tags: python, c++, esp32

I am trying to transfer an int array from python to an esp 32 board using asyncUDP on esp 32 and socket on python. Character arrays are passed without problems (using encode()) if you write them to char on esp, but when I decided to pass int, I couldn't do it. Using Bytes, python transmits them, but the ESP cannot read them. What can be fixed?

```
#python
while 1:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
    msg=(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,240)
    client.sendto(bytes(msg), (host, port))
    try:
        d = client.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        continue
    reply = d[0]
    addr = d[1]
    print ('Server reply: ' + reply.decode('utf-8'))



//c++
#include <AsyncUDP.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include<ESPmDNS.h>

int rdata[10] {0};

const size_t glen = sizeof(rdata) / sizeof(rdata[0]);

void parsePacket(AsyncUDPPacket packet)
{ 

Serial.println("packet recieved");
const int* tmp = (int*)packet.data();
const size_t len = packet.length() / glen;
if (tmp != nullptr && len == 1) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < glen; i++) {
        rdata[i] = tmp[i];
    }
    packet.printf("recieved %d\n", glen);
}
}
```

here is the data coming in

```
22:59:58.764 -> 67305985
22:59:58.764 -> 134678021
22:59:58.764 -> 1158348809
22:59:58.797 -> 1918986323
22:59:58.797 -> 892939621
22:59:58.797 -> 1594373169
22:59:58.797 -> 1886546273
22:59:58.797 -> 75063660
22:59:58.797 -> 1885566047
22:59:58.797 -> 1668246533
```

Comment: tpython is sending your data as a byte for each value, but your c++ code is assuming a series of ints. If you are sending data values 0 - 9, then bytes are fine, you need to receive them as bytes.

Comment: In general, use [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to convert numbers (of any kind) to bytes as it allows you to control data type and endianness.

Comment: i need to use 0-255 values. How can i send a series of int?
I tried using the series, but it still doesn't work.
msg=pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
client.sendto(bytes(msg), (host, port))
00:58:14.589 -> 50462976
00:58:14.589 -> 117835012
00:58:14.589 -> -1205073656
00:58:14.589 -> -689279388
00:58:14.589 -> 134280495
00:58:14.589 -> -1091599414
00:58:14.589 -> 1450761901
00:58:14.589 -> -1094927699
00:58:14.589 -> 305414140
00:58:14.589 -> 1616826

Comment: struct doesnt work too :((
    msg=struct.pack('hhhhhhhhhh',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
    client.sendto(msg, (host, port))

Could an incorrect packet size be transmitted/received?

Comment: msg=struct.pack('hhhhhhhhhh',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0) client.sendto(msg, (host, port))
transmited 20 packets
msg=struct.pack('bbbbbbbbbb',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0) client.sendto(msg, (host, port))
transmited 10 packets. i think thats 1 packet = 1 byte, maybe its incorrect

Comment: I solved the problem, it was necessary to replace int with uint8_t in the C++ code.
msg=struct.pack('10B',10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
client.sendto(msg, (host, port))
and c++ 
uint8_t rdata[10] {0};
const uint8_t* tmp = (uint8_t*)packet.data(); 
thank you very much

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask: you are sending 10 bytes, but expecting to receive 10 4-byte integers.